# Error: Only one # is allowed per tab

Tags: macros, errors, luatex, lua

Whenever I try processing the following code it gives the error `Only one # is allowed per tab. ... .25ex\everycr {}\tabskip \z@skip \halign {##`.

Can someone let me know what is wrong with it?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mydot}[1]{\oalign{$#1$\cr\noalign{\kern -2.2ex}\hfil$\ldotp$\hfil\cr}}

\newcommand*{\replacementdot}[2]{%
\makeatletter
\directlua%
{str=#1 arr={#2}
    if arr[2]==nil
    then tex.sprint(string.sub(str, 1, arr[1]-1)..[[\mydot{]]..string.sub(str, arr[1], arr[1])..[[}]]..string.sub(str, arr[1]+1))
    else tex.sprint(string.sub(str, 1, arr[1]-1)..[[\mydot{]]..string.sub(str, arr[1], arr[1])..[[}]]..string.sub(str, arr[1]+1, arr[2]-1)..[[\mydot{]]..string.sub(str, arr[2], arr[2])..[[}]]..string.sub(str, arr[2]+1))
    end
}
\makeatother
}

\begin{document}

$\replacementdot{0.123}{3,4}$

\end{document}
```

Note that when I remove the macro `\replacementdot` and use `\mydot` directly, it works fine.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why that complicated definition instead of `\dot`?

Comment: @egreg: because it didn't work with the package `amsmath`.
Now, after trying @Ulrike's answer both work just fine .. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are expanding `\mydot` too early, use `\string\mydot` (I also removed the \makeatletter which does nothing there).

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mydot}[1]{\oalign{$#1$\cr\noalign{\kern -2.2ex}\hfil$\ldotp$\hfil\cr}}

\newcommand*{\replacementdot}[2]{%
\directlua%
{str=#1 arr={#2}
    if arr[2]==nil
    then tex.sprint(string.sub(str, 1, arr[1]-1)..[[\string\mydot{]]..string.sub(str, arr[1], arr[1])..[[}]]..string.sub(str, arr[1]+1))
    else tex.sprint(string.sub(str, 1, arr[1]-1)..[[\string\mydot{]]..string.sub(str, arr[1], arr[1])..[[}]]..string.sub(str, arr[1]+1, arr[2]-1)..[[\string\mydot{]]..string.sub(str, arr[2], arr[2])..[[}]]..string.sub(str, arr[2]+1))
    end
}}

\begin{document}

$\replacementdot{0.123}{3,4}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Minor critique: It's **too** early rather than **to** early.

Comment: @DavidHammen corrected ;-)